# Java Doublebuffer - Why do we clear exposed area?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am new in Java graphics so little explanation would be helpful.

I found this snippet on Java double buffering, in which I don't understand why do we clear the exposed area, which we had just loaded with graphics.

It looks like we loaded it with graphics and right after that we clean it? But why?  (3rd code block)

Any explanation about it and beyond it would be helpful.

```
class DoubleBufferedCanvas extends Canvas {

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        Graphics offgc;
        Image offscreen = null;
        Dimension d = size();

        // create the offscreen buffer and associated Graphics
        offscreen = createImage(d.width, d.height);
        offgc = offscreen.getGraphics();

        // clear the exposed area  ----------- T H I S    B L O C K --------
        offgc.setColor(getBackground());
        offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        offgc.setColor(getForeground());

        // do normal redraw
        paint(offgc);
        // transfer offscreen to window
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what ever was previously painted to the offscreen image will still be there.

First of all, this is not Swing, it's AWT

Try and think about it like this.  In Swing (and many other graphics based frameworks) work like a artiest canvas, where what ever was painted onto it first, will still remain unless you paint over it first

Let's have a closer look at the code...

```
// Reference to the image's Graphics context
Graphics offgc;
// Backing image
Image offscreen = null;
// Current size of the component
Dimension d = size();

// create the offscreen buffer and associated Graphics
offscreen = createImage(d.width, d.height);
// Get a reference to the backing buffer's Graphics context
offgc = offscreen.getGraphics();

// The image has a default color (black I think), so we
// fill it with components current background color
// clear the exposed area  ----------- T H I S    B L O C K --------
offgc.setColor(getBackground());
offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
// Set the default color to the foreground color
offgc.setColor(getForeground());

// do normal redraw
paint(offgc);
// transfer offscreen to window
g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
```

Now, it's possible that it's just not required as one of the things the `paint` method will try and do is fill the `Graphics` context with the background color itself.  Also, instead of calling `paint(offgc);`, the code should probably be calling `super.update(offgc);` instead...

I would also suggest not bothering with the snipet and instead focus on using Swing components which are already double buffered or using a [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) if you want to take control over the painting process generally.

Also, have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in AWT and Swing

Comment: thanks for explanation, but i am still not clear about a point:  i guess, offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height); works like we are filling the whole rectangle with specified color, but not the graphicals content in the image. they stay untouched.(kinda fill background with specified color) am i right?  and what is the purspose of using offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);

Comment: No, not really.  `Graphics` is just a means which allows you to paint pixels to a target (in this case the image and the screen), it's just a commonalised API.  So when you call `fillRect`, it's actually drawing/filling the pixels in the target.  In this, the purpose is to make the image filled with the background color.  As I said, I believe that `createImage` creates an image with a black background, which isn't particularly pretty

Comment: ok.   so i create an empty  image with size of (100px; 100px) all of the 1000 pixels of it are "free". then i  call getGraphics on this image, --> images are drawn on it,  filling("occuping") (for example)100 pixels  out 1000. next - if i use fillRect  remaining 900pixels will be filled with specified color.

Comment: Something like that ;)

Comment: It fills the specified area with the specified color.  You should also have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)